# Java: Delimiters and regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I'm using the scanner method to do work on a string and need to filter out junk

here's the sample string

```
5/31/1948@14:57
```

I need to strip out the / @  :

Theres this doc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

But it's really confusing.

Comment: What do you mean, strip them out?  It looks like you've got a date-time string there; if you remove those characters you'll be left with a meaningless sequence of digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to split it up, use [`String#split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String[] parts = "5/31/1948@14:57".split("[/@:]");
```

Comment: I wound up using a variation of this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the replaceAll method as:

```
String filetredStr = inputStr.replaceAll("[@/:]","");
```

And if you want to delete any non-digit you can do:

```
String filetredStr = inputStr.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:-

```
s.replaceAll("[\\/@:]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `replaceAll(a,b)` is as follows:

```
String str = "5/31/1948@14:57";
String charsToRemove = "/@:";
for (int i = 0; i < charsToRemove.length(); i++) {
    str = str.replace(charsToRemove.charAt(i)+"", "");
}
```